# Fullcalendar custom view click on event

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am using fullcalendar 5 and have created a custom view according to the [documentaion](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js)

In may calendar configuration I have added this `eventClick: (info) => this.displayDetail(info)` it work great with the default views but can't figure out how to trigger the eventClick from my customview

How could I trigger it.

**Customview configuration:**

```js
import { sliceEvents, createPlugin } from '@fullcalendar/core'

const CustomViewConfig = {
  classNames: ['list-view'],
  duration: {
    month: 1.5
  },
  buttonText: 'Planning',

  content (props, element) {
    let html = '<div class="row">'
    const events = sliceEvents(props, false)

    for (const event of events) {
      html += `
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 event color-${event.def.sourceId}">
                <div class="row mb-4">
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <div class="col-date">
                            <span>${event.range.start.getDate()} ${event.range.start.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' })}</span>
                            <span>${event.range.end.getDate()} ${event.range.end.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' })}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-8">
                      <div class="col-content">
                          ${event.def.title}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      `
    }

    html += '</div>'

    return { html: html }
  }
}

export default createPlugin({
  views: {
    custom: CustomViewConfig
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi! It's been a long time since the question was asked, but have you found any solution?